# AngularJS recursive directive with click event and $http get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a novice in angular.js and I have to create an application that displays a table of content inside nested dropdown lists (e.g. the user clicks on link to view subchapters under chapters and then can go deeper and deeper).
Since my table of content is too large to be loaded at once, I want each subchapters list to be loaded only once the user clicks on the parent chapter.

I got to a point where I can display lvl2 chapters after clicking on a lvl1 chapter (as expected). However, once I click on a lvl2 chapter, my log shows the corresponding lvl3 appearing in the scope but then the log is called again and show the scope as it was before I clicked.

I found many answers about recursive directories, click events and $http get but I can't figure out how to properly combined these three things. I've been going in circle for days. I am tired and depressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have (slightly simplified):

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('entry', entryDirective)
    .directive('entries', entriesDirective)

function entryDirective($http) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            id: '@'
        },
        link: link,
        template: '<a href="#">{{title}}</a><entries/>'
    }
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {
            $http.get('modules/entries.xql?id=' + scope.id, { cache: false }).then(function(resp) {
                scope.entries = resp.data;;
            });
            console.log(scope);
        });
    };
}

function entriesDirective($compile) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    }
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var list = '<ul>' +
            '<li ng-repeat="entry in entries">' +
                '<entry id="{{entry.id}}" title="{{entry.title}}"/>' +
            '</li></ul>';
        var el = $compile(list)(scope);
        element.replaceWith(el);
    };
}
```

Hereunder is the HTML source. $ctrl.toc was set by another part of the application (works fine).

```
<ul class="nav">
      <li data-ng-repeat="entry in $ctrl.toc.content">
            <entry id="{{entry.id}}" title="{{entry.title}}"/>
      </li>
</ul>
```

And the output:

```
<ul class="nav">
      <li data-ng-repeat="entry in $ctrl.toc.content" class="ng-scope">
           <entry id="1.7.2" title="Title 1" class="ng-isolate-scope">
               <a href="#" class="ng-binding">Title 1</a>
               <ul class="ng-scope">
                   <li ng-repeat="entry in entries.entry" class="ng-scope">
                       <entry id="1.7.2.6" title="Title 2" ng-hide="entry.link" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                           <a href="#" class="ng-binding">Title 2</a>
                           <ul class="ng-scope">
                           <!-- list items appear for a sec then dissappear -->
                           </ul>
                       </entry>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </entry>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Instantiating directives with self-closing tags has been known to cause problems. Replace `<entries/>` with `<entries></entries>`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Changing it did not correct the problem but it's good to know anyway :)

Comment: Update: I tried something completely different and I stil get some sort of weird refresh after getting the scope I needed. I now think it has something to do with ui-router. Still don't know what to do about it though...

Comment: The two component directives mix paradigms. One has isolate scope with declarative data bindings. The other is no scope with subterranean binding of data. This mixing of paradigms makes the code difficult to understand, test, debug, and maintain. This leads to going in circle for days, exhaustion, and depression. Just use the AngularJS declarative style. Stop trying to be so fancy.